# Frictional force on an inclined plane, with 2 different planes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

So the question is as follows:

The speed of the 8.0 $kg$ mass in position **A** in the figure is 6.0 $ms^{-1}$. By the time it gets to **B** the speed is measured to be 12.0 $ms^{-1}$. What is the frictional force opposing the motion?

This object is resting on the top of an inclined plane, at a height of 12$m$ from the ground, and the angle of incline is 30°.

See attached photo:
[image]

Comment: Quick hint use energy conservation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,
Sin 30° = 12/AB
=> AB = 24

We will use work energy theorem to solve this question.

Work done by all forces = Change in kinetic energy of the block.

Work (mg) + Work (Friction) = ∆K.E.

mgh - f(AB) = 1/2*m*(v^2 - v^2)

8*10*12 - f*24 = 1/2 * 8 * (12^2 - 6^2)

f = 22N

Note : Here friction does negative work as direction of motion is opposite to friction force.

Hope this helps. :-)